# Could really use some feedback on this registration code in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was hoping someone could give me some feedback on my code. I am still new to php and I'm sure I have messed up somewhere. The code pasted is for a registration page where users will submit their information which will then be posted to the database.

```
<?php>
include 'PasswordHash.php';


$sql = new mysqli('localhost', '#######', '#####', '######');

// Create an array to catch any errors in the registration form.
$errors = array();

/**
 * Make sure the form has been submitted before trying to process it. This is
 * single most common cause of 'undefined index' notices.
 */
if (!empty($_POST))
{
    // First check that required fields have been filled in.
    if (empty($_POST['username']))
    {
        $errors['username'] = "Username cannot be empty.";
    }


    // Restrict usernames to alphanumeric plus space, dot, dash, and underscore.
    /*
    if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 .-_]/', $_POST['username']))
    {
        $errors['username'] = "Username contains illegal characters.";
    }
    */
    if (empty($_POST['firstname']))
    {
        $errors['firstname'] = "First Name cannot be empty.";
    }

    if (empty($_POST['surname']))
    {
        $errors['surname'] = "Surname cannot be empty.";
    }

    if (empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $errors['password'] = "Password cannot be empty.";
    }


    if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 8)
    {
        $errors['password'] = "Password must be at least 8 charcaters.";
    }


    // Force passwords to contain at least one number and one special character.
    /*
    if (!preg_match('/[0-9]/', $_POST['password']))
    {
        $errors['password'] = "Password must contain at least one number.";
    }
    if (!preg_match('/[\W]/', $_POST['password']))
    {
        $errors['password'] = "Password must contain at least one special character.";
    }
    */

    if (empty($_POST['password_confirm']))
    {
        $errors['password_confirm'] = "Please confirm password.";
    }

    if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password_confirm'])
    {
        $errors['password'] = "Passwords do not match.";
    }

    $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if (!$email)
    {
        $errors['email'] = "Not a valid email address.";
    }

    /**
     * Escape the data we're going to use in our query. Never trust user input.
     */
    $username = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $email    = $sql->real_escape_string($email);
    $firstname    = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
    $surname    = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST['surname']);
    $addressline1    = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST['addressline1']);
    $addressline2    = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST['addressline2']);
    $city    = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
    $county    = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST['county']);
    $postcode   = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST['postcode']);

    /**
     * Check that the username and email aren't already in our database.
     *
     * Note also the absence of SELECT *

     */
    $query  = "SELECT username, email
               FROM users
               WHERE username = '{$username}' OR email = '{$email}'";
    $result = $sql->query($query);

    /**
     * There may well be more than one point of failure, but all we really need
     * is the first one.
     */
    $existing = $result->fetch_object();

    if ($existing)
    {
        if ($existing->username == $_POST['username'])
        {
            $errors['username'] = "That username is already in use.";
        }
        if ($existing->email == $email)
        {
            $errors['email'] = "That email address is already in use.";
        }
    }
}



if (!empty($_POST) && empty($errors))
{
    /**
     * Hash password before storing in database
     */
    $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, FALSE);
    $password = $hasher->HashPassword($_POST['password']);

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, surname, username,email, password, addressline1, addressline2, city, county, postcode, created)
              VALUES ('{$firstname}','{$surname}','{$username}','{$email}', 
              '{$password}','{$addressline1}','{$addressline2}','{$city}','{$county}','{$postcode}', NOW())";
    $success = $sql->query($query);

    if ($success)
    {
        $message = "Account created.";
    }
    else
    {
        $errors['registration'] = "Account could not be created. Please try again later.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `<?php>` is wrong. It should be just `<?php`.

Comment: You check if $_POST is not empty twice. Just nest your check for errors inside the first !empty clause.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here are my notes from looking through the code:

1. You create a connection to the database, and include `PasswordHash.php`, when it is not yet needed. Database connections are not "free of charge" and should be used conservatively.
2. You use two `if` blocks where you could use just one.
3. There is no real checking/validation/sanitation of the incoming data. Sure, you escape it before you `INSERT` it, but you never check if it is valid. For example, the `$county` variable is just assumed to be a county... it could be anything.
4. The first `SELECT` query may not be entirely necessary. If your database schema is set up properly (i.e. using `UNIQUE` on the `username` and `email` fields), then you will be told that the user already exists. You can then take it from there. If is always a good deal if you can eliminate database calls.
5. The `$errors` array is never used. You probably know this, so I will not use any time on it.

The main problem (if you want to call it that) is that you need to be a little more systematic. You need to think about the whole process in steps, or more as an algorithm:

1. Sanitize the input
2. Validate the input

   1. If the input does not validate, stop, let the user correct it
   2. If the input is valid, go to #3
3. Set up database connection
4. Insert data

   1. If there is a duplicate record error, stop, the user already exists!
   2. If there is no error, go to #5
5. Success, user was created. DONE.

That is about it.